# JSON Formatting error

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I am getting this error while trying to import this JSON into google bigquery table
file-00000000: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. (error code: invalid)
JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0 at file: file-00000000. Start of array encountered without start of object. (error code: invalid)

This is the JSON

```
[{'instrument_token': 11192834, 'average_price': 8463.45, 'last_price': 8471.1, 'last_quantity': 75, 'buy_quantity': 1065150, 'volume': 5545950, 'depth': {'buy': [{'price': 8471.1, 'quantity': 300, 'orders': 131072}, {'price': 8471.0, 'quantity': 300, 'orders': 65536}, {'price': 8470.95, 'quantity': 150, 'orders': 65536}, {'price': 8470.85, 'quantity': 75, 'orders': 65536}, {'price': 8470.7, 'quantity': 225, 'orders': 65536}], 'sell': [{'price': 8471.5, 'quantity': 150, 'orders': 131072}, {'price': 8471.55, 'quantity': 375, 'orders': 327680}, {'price': 8471.8, 'quantity': 1050, 'orders': 65536}, {'price': 8472.0, 'quantity': 1050, 'orders': 327680}, {'price': 8472.1, 'quantity': 150, 'orders': 65536}]}, 'ohlc': {'high': 8484.1, 'close': 8336.45, 'low': 8422.35, 'open': 8432.75}, 'mode': 'quote', 'sell_quantity': 998475, 'tradeable': True, 'change': 1.6151959167271395}]
```

http://jsonformatter.org/ also gives parse error for this JSON block. Need help understanding where the formatting is wrong - this is the JSON from a rest API

Comment: As explained by the @user94559 , first you convert json data to valid format. Then convert that into `ndjson` and upload. It's works!. You can use [online tool](https://www.json-to-ndjson.app/) to convert json to ndjson.

Answer (score 11):

This is not valid JSON. JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes. Also, `True` should be `true`.

If I had to guess, I would guess that this is Python code being passed off as JSON. :-)

I suspect that even once this is made into correct JSON, it's not the format Google BigQuery is expecting. From https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-formats#json_format, it looks like you should have a text file with one JSON object per line. Try just this:

```
{"mode": "quote", "tradeable": true, "last_quantity": 75, "buy_quantity": 1065150, "depth": {"buy": [{"quantity": 300, "orders": 131072, "price": 8471.1}, {"quantity": 300, "orders": 65536, "price": 8471.0}, {"quantity": 150, "orders": 65536, "price": 8470.95}, {"quantity": 75, "orders": 65536, "price": 8470.85}, {"quantity": 225, "orders": 65536, "price": 8470.7}], "sell": [{"quantity": 150, "orders": 131072, "price": 8471.5}, {"quantity": 375, "orders": 327680, "price": 8471.55}, {"quantity": 1050, "orders": 65536, "price": 8471.8}, {"quantity": 1050, "orders": 327680, "price": 8472.0}, {"quantity": 150, "orders": 65536, "price": 8472.1}]}, "change": 1.6151959167271395, "average_price": 8463.45, "ohlc": {"close": 8336.45, "high": 8484.1, "open": 8432.75, "low": 8422.35}, "instrument_token": 11192834, "last_price": 8471.1, "sell_quantity": 998475, "volume": 5545950}
```

Comment: JSONformatter.org gives error even with double quotes

Comment: @ChandanKumar: But fundamentally, the answer is: **That's not JSON**, which was something you could trivially have determined yourself. Don't hand-craft JSON, build a structure in whatever language/environment you're using and use a proper JSON serializer to create the JSON.

Comment: update: This JSON shown as valid in JSONformatter.org(single quotes replaced by double quotes, True replaced by "True") but google bigquery still gives same error.

Comment: Start as an object, not array: {"data": [...]}

Comment: @smarx Thank..this is python code passed off as JSON by the data vendor :). Original JSON was also in line delimited format(start and end in same line). Getting same error with the JSON you posted.

Comment: @ChandanKumar You're getting "Start of array encountered without start of object." at position 0 with my JSON? Seems unlikely, since there's no start of an array there. Are you *sure* you're using my JSON?

Comment: @smarx working now. Thanks :). Google Bigquery threw an error but data was updated in table.

Answer (score 6):

OP has a valid JSON record but that wouldn't work with Biq Query, and here's why:

1. **Google Big Query** supports, JSON objects `{}`, one object per line. Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#bigquery-import-gcs-file-python) out.
2. This basically means that you cannot supply list `[]` as json records and expect Big Query to detect it. You must always have one json object per line.
3. Here's a quick reference to what I am saying.

[image: (Image courtesy: json.org)]
*and there are more.*

---

### at last,

I highly recommend you read up the below and check out the link for more information on different forms of JSON structures, read this from the **[json.org](https://www.json.org/)**

---